# Get all include paths, lib etc. needed by a Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I'm creating another build automation tool but I'd need to get the finale variable contents , as they are in the makefile produced by qmake, but without generating all the makefile...
Is there a way (by creating another template for example, or querying qmake...) to get all the includes, the links etc... ?

(no matter the output format, I just want the path in a fast way)

PS : I've already tried to use message() on the qmake variable, but it outs empty strings

Comment: Take a look at [CMake](https://qt-project.org/quarterly/view/using_cmake_to_build_qt_projects). It will give you more control over your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen the output of the command-line `qmake -query` ...?

On my system it gives (removed much of the output for clarity):

```
~ sez$ env PATH=$HOME/build/qt5/qtbase/bin qmake -query
QT_SYSROOT:
QT_INSTALL_PREFIX:/usr/local/Qt-5.2.0
QT_INSTALL_DATA:/usr/local/Qt-5.2.0
QT_INSTALL_HEADERS:/usr/local/Qt-5.2.0/include
QT_INSTALL_LIBS:/usr/local/Qt-5.2.0/lib
QMAKE_SPEC:macx-clang
QMAKE_VERSION:3.0
QT_VERSION:5.2.0
```

Its less verbose in earlier versions.  You can query individual variables like this:

```
~ sez$ env PATH=$HOME/build/qt5/qtbase/bin qmake -query QT_INSTALL_HEADERS
/usr/local/Qt-5.2.0/include
```

does that do what you need?  Beware of the fact that it will report the location the files are installed to by the `make install` at the time Qt was built.  That means that if you have built Qt but not run "make install" the results of qmake -query won't give you a useful answer.

If you have built from sources and want to use then out of that build directory, then you'd need to run `./configure -prefix=$PWD`, and then `make install`.

**EDIT:**

For one of my qmake generated Makefiles I have -

INCPATH = -I/usr/local/Qt-5.2.0/mkspecs/macx-clang -I/Users/sez/depot/plistinator/src -I/usr/local/Qt-5.2.0/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I/usr/local/Qt-5.2.0/lib/QtXml.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I/usr/local/Qt-5.2.0/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I/usr/local/Qt-5.2.0/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I. -I. -F/usr/local/Qt-5.2.0/lib

This is dependent on which Qt modules have been specified for example

```
QT += widgets xml
```

Given that information you could reconstruct the above INCPATH using whatever environment you're automating in, eg for bash shell expressions part of one might be

```
XML_INC=$(qmake -query QT_INSTALL_LIBS)/QtXml.framework/Versions/5/Headers
```

To get the mkspecs include you could do

```
MKSPEC_INC=$(qmake -query QT_INSTALL_PREFIX)/mkspecs/$(qmake -query QMAKE_SPEC)
```

With respect to the GL paths in the SDK those will always be included for Qt, so you could construct them by capturing the output from `gcc -v`.

Then combine all these *_INC vars into the final result.

Coming up with a complete script for this is beyond the scope of this answer but I think this approach would get you there.  I can't think of an easier way to do what you want without actually generating the Makefile.

Comment: it permits to get the install paths of Qt, and I think I can deduce the include and lib paths of each module.
But what I'd like id to get the INCPATH of the generated makefile without generate it

Comment: I've edited my answer to hopefully address the INCPATH requirement you mention.

Comment: That what I did thanks :)
by the way, Qt have cute name convention that make easy to retrieve the includes and libs from the module name. just to manage the Qt versions.

Moreover, there is also pkg-config which give useful informations about libs that my script can use.

see https://gitorious.org/yabat/yabat/ if you want to view my script